# How do I hide the download button on the audio player?

Tags: media

I want to hide the "download" button on the audio player provided by the Media module in Drupal 8.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Create a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) if you haven't already.
2. Find the file `core/modules/file/templates/file-audio.html.twig` and copy it to your subtheme's `templates` directory.
3. Edit the following line in the file.

Original line:

`<audio {{ attributes }}>`

Change it to this:

`<audio {{ attributes }} controlsList="nodownload">`

Comment: You should also be able to preprocess this to add onto the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For files uploaded into the private:// directory, you can restrict access via permissions.
Also, take a look for the [Protected File (from download)](https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_file) module.

Comment: Which permission allows you to restrict access to file downloads?